# MusiXTeX beam slope rendering problem

Tags: rendering, musixtex

I have the following code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\begin{document}
\setstaffs1{2}
\setclef1{6000}
\startextract

\Notes\Qqbl JMRM|\ibl0i{-1}\ztqb0{il}\sk\ztqb0{jm}\sk\ztqb0{il}\sk\ztqb0f\qb0i\en

\endextract    
\end{document}
```

That renders like this
[image]

What should I do in order to make it like this?

[image]

I have been reading a lot but have had no success in finding an example with code nor anyone with the same problem

Comment: If you don't mind the slope, reduce`\ibl0i{-1}` to `\ibl0i{0}`, the corner is cured. Otherwise please waiting for professional answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

skip the "t"s:[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}%
\usepackage{musixtex}%
\begin{document}%
\setstaffs1{2}%
\setclef1{6000}%
\startextract%
\Notes\Qqbl JMRM|\ibl0i{-1}\zqb0{il}\sk\zqb0{jm}\sk\zqb0{il}\sk\tbl0\zqb0f\qb0i\en%
\endextract%
\end{document}%
```